# Python Unicode: Can I get back my ñ?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I've read several SO questions and blog posts on how python deals with unicode, but I'm still a bit confused. I was scraping through scrapy and got this from a web page: `u'Isla de Se\xf1orita'`. It should be `u'Isla de Señorita'`. I know I can do something like..

```
>>> u"ñ"
u'\xf1'
>>> u"ñ".encode("utf-8")
'\xc3\xb1'
```

But what am I supposed to do with this? Can I get `u"ñ"` back out of these bytes? I just want the ñ so that I can save it to a field in a django model. Thanks.

Comment: Python is trying to be helpful here and produces ASCII-friendly debug output. ñ is U+00F1 in Unicode, so Python displays `\xf1` to indicate the value in a way that won't break even when copied and pasted into a terminal or editor that cannot handle anything but ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

your ñ is still there. it's just encoded differently. check out this action in my python interpreter:

```
>>> print '\xc3\xb1'
ñ
```

maybe i'm not clear on what you mean by "get it back"?

Comment: When I enter that same line of code, I get `├▒`, but if I `print u"ñ"`, I get back `ñ` Why is that? But anyway, I never tried printing it out >_<, so I can see what's going on now. I think my error is probably related to something else.

Comment: @pyramidface: writing UTF-8 to a terminal or console only works if that terminal or console is actually configured to handle UTF-8. Yours is not. See the post I closed yours as a duplicate of.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah okay, thanks for clearing that up.